# Java EE and struts and JSP: java form population - action bean etc

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts, dao

HI everyone.

ISSUE-

> Error populating nl.strohalm.cyclos.controls.cv.CvUploadForm@317bdd in /member/cvUpload
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate

I am working on a opensource wep app, and trying to teach my self some skills by adding new functionality.

Now The web app is called cyclos and uses - Java EE, Struts, Hibernate, JSP, Tiles-def (spring, MySql JavaScript) SETUP: controls, DAO's, services, entities etc.

I am trying to add new functionality such as a CV database for users to save a template and file.

My sample JSP form looks as follows:

```
<ssl:form method="post" action="/member/cvUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<html:hidden property="id" />
<html:hidden property="owner" />
<html:hidden property="uploadDate" />

<table class="defaultTableContent" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="tdHeaderTable">TITLE HERE PLEASE !!!></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="left" class="tdContentTableLists">
            <table class="defaultTable">
                <tr>
                    <th class="tdHeaderContents" width="30%"> CV Upload -> needs properties copy / ref !!!</th>
                    <th class="tdHeaderContents" width="60%">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Notes </td>
                    <td><cyclos:richTextArea name="notes"  styleId="descriptionText"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td><html:text value="address" size="25" property="address" /><br>
                        <html:text value="address" size="25" property="address2" />
                        <html:text value="address" size="25" property="address3" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone Number</td>
                    <td><html:text value="0791 000 000" size="15" property="phoneNumber"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Field of interest / industry</td>
                    <td><c:forEach var="industry" items="${industries}">
                            <label>
                                <html:radio property="industry" value="${industry}" styleClass="radio" /><bean:message key="cv.industries.${industry}" />
                            </label>
                            </c:forEach>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>CV upload</td>
                    <td><html:file property="cvContent" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" id="saveButton"  value="<bean:message key="global.submit"/>" align="center">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my java form populated by struts or how ever looks as follows:

```
public class CvUploadForm extends BaseBindingForm {

private Long                id;
@IndexedEmbedded(depth = 4)
private Member              owner;
// private Calendar                       creationDate;
// private Member                         memberId;
private FormFile                cvContent;
private Calendar            uploadDate;
private long                memberId;

public CvUploadForm() {
}

public CvUploadForm(Long id, Member owner, FormFile cvContent, Calendar uploadDate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.cvContent = cvContent;
    this.uploadDate = uploadDate;

}

public Map<String, Object> getCv() {
    return values;
}
public void setCv(final Map<String, Object> map) {
    values = map;
}

public void setCv(final String key, final Object value) {
    values.put(key, value);
}
```

//    ++        GETTERS AND SETTERS       ++

// =============================================

Now I can display my template, but my submit wont work -> and i would like to understand the issue / error shown im my output window !! (see at top and following error )

the next error shown is as follows :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke nl.strohalm.cyclos.controls.cv.CvUploadForm.setOwner - argument type mismatch

Plus couple more errors. (owner ov cv refers to different member table as ID - uses java enum - relationships... fetch

I am very grateful for any reply ! And mybe some clarification about the setup. I thought I onlu use the form to display bits on JSP, and the use the CV.java entity file for the maaping etc . . so I am a little lost on getting all files and the connection right as wel las understanding the error here

Thanks for any reply, if you need additional info pls let me know.
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to see what is the type of object it attempts to pass to the setOwner method. It is not an object of type Member.

Use your debugger and try to see what is trying to pass.

Comment: I am not to familiar with all this, and not sure about what debugger to use for that (ps: i use NetBeans) - I am using method to register binder called getWriteDataBinders. i have a meathod to read the CV context.getForm, - the databinder has a line for owner as follows:

Comment: "binder.registerBinder("owner", PropertyBinder.instance(Member.class, "owner", ReferenceConverter.instance(Member.class)));"

Comment: Please let me know if you know a debugger for those sort of issues ! thx for your raply in the first place !

Comment: Just use Debug instead of run in order to run your application in debug mode. Right click on your netbeans project and u will c Debug. Another thing you could do would be to change the method setOwner(Member meber) to setOwner(Object member) just to see what type of object it attempts to pass. You would set a breakpoint inside the setOwner method.

Comment: thx, I will have to use that debugger more . . a purling I never have - seems like a useful complex tool that needs bit of getting used to. Thx for that ! Not having solved the issue yet but will work with that for now ! thx

Answer (score 1):

you should precise if  it's Struts 1 or struts 2.
struts 1 maps proprities to actionForm ,if it's the case you should use primitive types in form action ( not objects like member) .
Struts 2 uses OGNL to map complex object to their specific bean.

this my first post on stack over flow , i hope that it khelps you.

Comment: Ja thats good to know, as far I am concerned it is 1.3.8 -> I am totally new to it, and go by how existing functions work. Coming to think of it, the forms are often pretty short and do not include all fields as on the JSP -> so what is the use of the form ? thanks you for ur reply !!

Comment: basically I have the form, the entity and the action class ! not to forget DAO and service files . . the display seems fine, when pressing submit i get several issues . .

Comment: in Struts 1 every action has it's corespending action form ,  as i know you should put in action form primitive types like (int , string...) then you do some buisiness logic in the correspending action to make your complex object like Member ----> actionForm must contain things like memberName ... rather then MemberObject